# Iterate a piece of code over a set of files

Tags: python, file, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I have written a piece of code which lets me extract the table from a file named 195775.html. I save the output in a text file. Now I need to iterate this code for all the 20,000 files which I have in the same directory. In addition, I also want the files to be tagged with their respective file names. i.e. each file should have a column (in the table) which takes the *filename* as its value. Also, I want the output text files to be named as per the input files (i.e. the names should match).

Here is my code:

```
import urllib2
import os
import time
import traceback
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

outfile= open('C:/Users/Manvendra/Dropbox/Python/195775.txt','wb')
rfile  = open('C:/Users/Manvendra/Dropbox/PRI/Data/AP/195775.html')
rsoup  = BeautifulSoup(rfile)
nodes  = rsoup.find('div',{'class':'frmhdtitle'})
if nodes!= None: 
    #print "div present"
    x = nodes.findNext('table')
    if x!= None:
     #print "table present"
     y = x.find('tbody')
     if y!= None:
      #print "tbody present"
      z= y.findAll('tr')
      if z!= None:
       #print "tr present"
       for wx in z[1:]:
        num=    wx.find('td').get_text()                     
        print num
        name=   wx.find('td').findNext('td').get_text()
        print name      
        age =   wx.find('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').get_text()
        print age
        caste=  wx.find('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').get_text()
        print caste
        gender= wx.find('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').get_text()
        print gender
        quali = wx.find('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').get_text()
        print quali
        occu  = wx.find('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').get_text()
        print occu
        #email  = wx.find('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').get_text()
        #print email
        #ward  = wx.find('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').get_text()
        #print ward
        resr  = wx.find('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').findNext('td').get_text()
        print resr
        outfile.write(str(num) +"\t" + str(name) +"\t" + str(age) +"\t" + str (caste) +"\t" + str(quali) +"\t" + str(occu) + "\t" + str(resr) + str(infile) +"\n") 
outfile.close()
```

Comment: You can iterate through your files with `os.listdir` and get the file names with `os.path.split` and `os.path.splitext`.

Comment: Also, a tip: you can just do something like: `tds = wx.find_all('td'); name = tds[1].get_text()` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your code into a separate function and call it for each html file in the directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import os
from glob import glob

dest_dir = 'C:/Users/Manvendra/Dropbox/Python'
for html_filename in glob('C:/Users/Manvendra/Dropbox/PRI/Data/AP/*.html'):
    basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(html_filename))[0]
    with open(html_filename, 'rb') as html_file, \
         open(os.path.join(dest_dir, basename + '.txt'), 'wb') as csv_file:
        html2csv(html_file, csv_file)
```

where  `html2csv()` is:

```
import logging
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def html2csv(html_file, csv_file):
    writerow = csv.writer(csv_file, dialect=csv.excel_tab).writerow
    div = BeautifulSoup(html_file).find('div', 'frmhdtitle')
    try:
        rows = div.find_next('table').tbody.find_all('tr')[1:]
    except AttributeError:
        log.warning("No info in %s file", html_file.name)
    else:
        for tr in rows:
            writerow([td.get_text().encode('utf-8')
                      for td in tr.find_all('td')[:8]] + [html_file.name])
```

Note: `findNext('td')` method in your code searches the html document without any regard for elements boundaries i.e., it may find `td` that belongs to a different row or even a different table as long as it is further in the document. I rewrote the loop assuming that you want to find eight adjacent `<td>` elements in each row.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
files = os.listdir(directoryPath)
for file in files:
    *your code*
```

Note that if you want to open the files you need to open the path: directoryPath + "/" + file.
Regarding all the tags and filenames you want to name the files, "file" is now a variable which contains the name of the file you are now processing so do with it what you want.